# Windows Update stuck looking for old updates (leftover from upgrading Win 10 to 11)

Tags: windows-11, windows-update

I had a Windows 10 system with a couple minor issues and one major - Windows Update was stuck and I never found a way to fix it. So I downloaded a Win 11 ISO and tried in-place upgrade, which works. But Windows Update is still stuck:

[image]

It still remembers those old updates. If I click "Retry all" it shows "Checking for updates" for two seconds and goes back to the same exact screen. If I click "retry" on the failing update it also spins for a couple seconds and spits the same error, but of course we don't even want to install Windows 10 2004 update onto Win 11. What I want is make it forget all this junk and run a proper update check from scratch.

- I have deleted the `SoftwareDistribution` and `catroot2` folders to no effect (a couple times by now)
- There is no pending.xml file
- `sfc /scannow` shows no problems
- `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` also runs fine all the way and doesn't do anything.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151902/discussion-on-question-by-violet-giraffe-windows-update-stuck-looking-for-old-up); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.